# An SPF setup example

Tags: email-server, centos5, spf

To set up SPF for an OpenEMM server (emm.example.com.sg) for the site:

```
domain: example.com.sg
web server: www.example.com.sg
EMM server: emm.example.com.sg (say, ip: 201.202.203.204)
```

The example.com.sg domain is registered by an outside supplier. What should I tell the supplier to set the TXT record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depents on what you want. If email from anything else than your MX server needs to be dropped, this will suffice:

`v=spf1 mx -all`

More examples can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework#Implementation)

And an answer based on the comments below:

`v=spf1 mx ip4:201.202.203.204 -all`

Comment: `emm.example.com.sg`, as a new server, will send emails directly from it's server by `sendmail`.

Comment: and is that also the incoming mailserver (MX record in DNS)?

Comment: no, `mx` is `mail.example.com.sg`

Comment: ok, updated answer

Comment: thanks! is `v=spf1 mx a:emm.example.com.sg -all` also good?

Comment: Yes, that would work too. Wikipedia doesn't make that clear, but http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax does.